# How to recreate 3D logo look with glow behind it?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

How could I recreate this 3D logo look with the glow behind too?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple way first. Model the shapes; apply an emission shader assigning it only to geometry in the background; turn on eevee bloom and make some of the emission material be seen by the camera. More involved way, use indirect light baking and light probe as described in the following video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvA---4SrgE